# How do I join the #tor-dev IRC channel

Tags: development, chat

I am new to the TOR network, and I want to get a good working knowledge of TOR so I can volunteer and contribute to some of the projects.

However, I cannot seem to join the #tor-dev channel. I have joined the #tor channel and that seems to work fine.

The way I joined #tor was using OFTC:

> https://www.oftc.net/

But when I try and enter #tor-dev in the top right box and join using my username (which I previously registered), I cannot see any other user or discussion.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way to join IRC is by using an own client. Here you can save your settings and easily join. However when you want to use the [Webchat](https://webchat.oftc.net/?channels=%23tor-dev&uio=d4) you also need to be identified.

So after you entered your nickname and #tor-dev as a channel the chat window opens. On the last line you enter:

```
/msg NickServ IDENTIFY YourPassword
```

When you have entered it and the password is correct, you can enter the channel.

However sometimes the channel is locked. In some cases nobody can enter the channel. So here you need to wait for some hours.

Tor also has a [document which guides you through the first steps](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/onboarding/IRC).

Comment: Note that the webchat actually blocks Tor, even if OFTC does not.